# Report an Error Problem: Point $X$ is on $\overline{AC}$ such that $AX = 3 CX = 12$. If $\angle ABC = \angle BXA = 90^\circ$, then what is $BX$?

Tags: geometry

Point $X$ is on $\overline{AC}$ such that $AX = 3 CX = 12$. If $\angle ABC = \angle BXA = 90^\circ$, then what is $BX$?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple geometry. The triangles $ABC,BXC,AXB$ are all similar. You are given $AX=12,XC=4$. So it is easy to find the other lengths. Eg $\frac{XC}{BC}=\frac{BC}{AC}$, so $BC=8$ and hence $BX=4\sqrt3$.

[image]